# Regex: getting past a negative lookahead

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having trouble with a negative lookahead in JavaScript. This may seem like a silly thing to regex, but it's still something I'm trying to figure out.

Say I have the following string:

```
>>a+b+c
```

and I know that the first two characters (a,b) can be in any order, but the last character (c) must be last. The characters cannot be repeated, and all characters must be separated by a plus (+).

I am using a negative lookahead in the following manner:

```
^>>(?:([ab+])(?!.*\1))*$
```

Testing the following strings works until this point:

```
>>a+b //true, as expected
>>b+a //true, as expected
```

However, when I try to move beyond the negative lookahead, I can't seem to get things to work:

```
^>>(?:([ab+])(?!.*\1))*\+c$
```

Test the following strings:

```
>>a+b+c //false, expecting true
>>b+a+c //false, expecting true
```

What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your capture matches the single `+` in the pattern which then cannot be repeated (that is, the repetition of `+` in your input makes the match fail).

Try this regex instead:

```
^>>(?:([ab])\+(?!.*\1))*c$
```

Comment: I think I understand. So anything captured in the first capture (which passes to the negative lookahead), will then be ignored. So, by moving the `\+` out of the capture, it cannot be passed to the lookahead. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: @KevBot Kind of. You can also leave it in the capture like this: `^>>(?:([ab]\+)(?!.*\1))*c$` and it will still work. That's because the capure will be `a+` and then `b+`, which both are not repeated before the `c`. However, in your initial solution, the capture was `a`, then `+` - and right then it fails because another `+` is found between `b` and `c`.

Comment: I see. Thank you for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a . before your last *.  You want to match characters after doing the lookahead check, not match 0 or more of the whole check. (Assuming you only want a+b+c or b+a+c to match, although if those are the only to combos, you might just literally match those two with an or.)

```
^>>(?:([ab+])(?!.*\1)).*\+c$
```

I believe that will also match just **a+c** so this might be what you want instead:

```
^>>(?:([ab])\+(?!\1)).\+c$
```